# How to identify torrent file pieces in µTP

Tags: bittorrent, torrent

As piece index is provided for pieces of file transferred using BitTorrent protocol, is there something similar to identify the transferred piece while using µTP. While capturing the network packets using `Wireshark`, it shows no messages similar to the peer messages of `BitTorrent` protocol.

Comment: Do you have the bt-utp dissector enabled?

Comment: I am not sure of that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from looking on their bugtracker it seems like treating µTP as a transport protocol isn't implemented:
https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8792

Comment: Thanks for the information. But it is said that `The uTP extension has been supported since r36716.` in (http://wiki.wireshark.org/Reassemble%20BitTorrent%20messages%20spanning%20multiple%20TCP%20segments)

Comment: r36716 predates that bug, which leads me to conclude that the bug is still current. It just has a µTP dissector, that doesn't mean it's treating it as a transport protocol.